# Join query not working properly while connecting two tables

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6

Here i am doing cab allocation module,here i will explain my requirement,admin allocate the cab to the employees in shift wise.this details i stored in cab_allocation allocation table.

> cab_allocation (Table Name)

```
allocationId                date                  cabId    shiftTiming

1                         2017-08-12              CBX100     1
2                         2017-08-12              CBX100     2
3                         2017-08-12              CBX101     3
```

Here **cabId** CBX100 having two allocation and CBX101 having one allocation per day. after this i want to track this trip is happening or not, for this tracking details i stored in trip_details table

> trip_details (table name)

```
tripId    cabNo    shiftId   tripDate   startTime   endTime    tripStatus

 1       CBX100      1       2017-08-12  09:30:00    11:30:00       1
 2       CBX100      2       2017-08-12  12.10.00                    0
```

Here cabId CBX100 has completed his shiftId 1, shiftId start time is 09:30:00 and end time 11:30:00  and tripStatus 1 that means this trip is completed.

Next cabId CBX100 has started second shift, start time is 12.10.00 , but this trip is not completed so there is no end time and tripstatus

Next cabId CBX101 has not started his trip, so there is no entry is this table,

Now my expected result is which are the trip is incomplete i want to take details in cab allocation. here cab_allocation table allocationId i am using forien key trip_details table tripId.

> I tried but i am not getting exact result,because CBX101 cabId not yet started his trip ,so entry not there in trip_details table, so i am not able get details.

I Tried like this

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cab_allocation` a INNER JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId=b.tripId WHERE b.tripStatus !='1'";
  $mysql = mysql_query($sql);
  $count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
  if($count > 0){
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
  $arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
  echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }else{
    $arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
    echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }
```

I am getting Results

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "allocationId": "2",
        "date": "2017-08-12",
        "shiftTiming": "2",
        "routeId": "1",
        "cabId": "CBX100",
        "tripId": "2",
        "cabNo": "CBX100",
        "driverId": "G2E100",
        "shiftId": "2",
        "tripDate": "",
        "startTime": "12.10.0",
        "endTime": "",
        "tripStatus": "0"
    }
]
```

}

Expected Results

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "allocationId": "2",
        "date": "2017-08-12",
        "shiftTiming": "2",
        "cabId": "CBX100",
    },
    {
        "allocationId": "3",
        "date": "2017-08-12",
        "shiftTiming": "3",
        "cabId": "CBX101",
    },
]
}
```

Comment: How can we help without seeing any code or SQL?

Comment: Oh sorry, wait i will upload my code

Comment: Mr@ Felippe Duarte,Please see my updated code, i uploaded what i tried

Answer (score 0):

The proper SQL would be:

```
    SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId
      FROM cab_allocation a
LEFT JOIN trip_details b 
        ON a.allocationId = b.tripId
     WHERE b.tripStatus !='1'
```

LEFT JOIN will match records on cab_allocation that isn't on trip_details

Comment: Mr@Felippe Duarte, i used  your code but i am getting {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "allocationId": "2",
            "date": "2017-08-12",
            "shiftTiming": "2",
            "cabId": "CBX100"
        }
    ]
}
,

Comment: {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "allocationId": "2",
            "date": "2017-08-12",
            "shiftTiming": "2",
            "cabId": "CBX100",
        },
  {
            "allocationId": "3",
            "date": "2017-08-12",
            "shiftTiming": "3",
            "cabId": "CBX101",
        },
    ]
}

Comment: I shared my expected answer please check

Answer (score 0):

User LEFT JOIN Instead Of INNER JOIN

```
SELECT a.* FROM cab_allocation as a 
LEFT JOIN 
trip_details as b ON a.allocationId=b.tripId 
WHERE b.tripStatus !='1'
```

[image]

This image will definitely help you

Comment: I used LEFT Join but i am getting exact anser,i am getting one value only,cabId CBX101 is not yet started that also i want , but i am not getting

Comment: Sorry i  am not getting my expected answer,please check and update my answer